# Using GDB to load 2 programs, only connect the 2nd to the remote target after the completion of the first

Tags: gdb, embedded, remote-debugging, openocd

I want to load 2 programs in the same GDB session using inferior, however I only want program 2 to run after the breakpoint event from program 1. When this event is reached, I want to connect my 2nd program so as not to disconnect GDB from the device causing a reset on the remote device.
This task i want to be automated to enable running of many tests in a series of tests. This code is in my .sh script run on cygwin.

Here is a sample of the code i have been trying to run;

```
gdb -batch -l 20 \
  -ex "target extended-remote localhost:3333" \
  -ex "load ${progA}" \
  -ex "add-inferior -exec ${progB} -no-connection" \
  -ex "run" \
  -ex "inferior infno" \
  -ex "target extended-remote localhost:3333" \
  -ex "continue"
```

The result is the disconnection of GDB from the target causing a device reset when the connection is re-established. I also move past the breakpoint event.

Comment: What does `inferior infno` do?  Usually the inferior command switches based on an inferior id, so I would expect something like `inferior 2` (in this case).

Comment: From my last look at documentation,, "infno" switches to the next runnable inferior. I may not know what id the next one is if the 2nd Inferior ID was a concurrent program.

Comment: I don't believe that `infno` has any special meaning for the `inferior` command.  The use of `infno` in the manual is just a placeholder for the inferior number.  I can't see any code that catches/handles `infno` inside GDB, and a quick experiment would suggest that it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: So, presume that we do not know the inferior number is, is it possible or not possible to switch to the next runnable without knowing its inferior number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the use of `inferior infno`, this isn't a thing, there's no convenience variable or keyword that means switch to an inferior that is not otherwise running.

However, you can create a convenience function in Python that does what you want.  Add the following to a `nri.py` file:

```
class next_runnable_inferior(gdb.Function):
  """Return the number of the next runnable inferior."""

  def __init__(self):
      super ().__init__("next_runnable_inferior")

  def invoke(self):
    for inf in gdb.inferiors():
      if len(inf.threads()) == 0:
        return inf.num
    raise gdb.GdbError("All inferiors are running")

next_runnable_inferior()
```

Then inside a GDB session:

```
(gdb) source /tmp/nri.py
(gdb) inferior $next_runnable_inferior()
[Switching to inferior 1 [<null>] (<noexec>)]
(gdb) add-inferior
[New inferior 2]
Added inferior 2
(gdb) inferior $next_runnable_inferior()
[Switching to inferior 1 [<null>] (<noexec>)]
(gdb) file /tmp/hello.x
Reading symbols from /tmp/hello.x...
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x401198: file /tmp/hello.c, line 18.
Starting program: /tmp/hello.x

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at /tmp/hello.c:18
18    printf ("Hello World\n");
(gdb) inferior $next_runnable_inferior()
[Switching to inferior 2 [<null>] (<noexec>)]
(gdb) file /tmp/hello.x
Reading symbols from /tmp/hello.x...
(gdb) inferior $next_runnable_inferior()
[Switching to inferior 2 [<null>] (/tmp/hello.x)]
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x401198: -qualified main. (2 locations)
Starting program: /tmp/hello.x

Thread 2.1 "hello.x" hit Temporary breakpoint 2.2, main () at /tmp/hello.c:18
18    printf ("Hello World\n");
(gdb) inferior $next_runnable_inferior()
All inferiors are running
(gdb) inferior 1
[Switching to inferior 1 [process 188577] (/tmp/hello.x)]
[Switching to thread 1.1 (process 188577)]
#0  main () at /tmp/hello.c:18
18    printf ("Hello World\n");
(gdb) kill
Kill the program being debugged? (y or n) y
[Inferior 1 (process 188577) killed]
(gdb) inferior 2
[Switching to inferior 2 [process 188613] (/tmp/hello.x)]
[Switching to thread 2.1 (process 188613)]
#0  main () at /tmp/hello.c:18
18    printf ("Hello World\n");
(gdb) inferior $next_runnable_inferior()
[Switching to inferior 1 [<null>] (/tmp/hello.x)]
(gdb)
```